# TwentyTwelve, where is the excerpt box in add new?

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

When i try to add a new post, the is no excerpt box. Does anyone know a way to enable this?

Answer (score 3):

Check that it is turned on inside the Screen Options at the top.

[image: screen options for Excerpt]